# Java architecture issue for extending instances (need for a pattern recommendation)

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, dynamic, extend

A service from external API which I am not allowed to modify returns me

```
  MyClass instance = ServiceUtil.getThing();
```

I would like to extend this returned class and Add/Override a method but leave intacts the others, say 150 methods.

```
  private class MyWrapperClass extends MyClass(){
      public MyWrapperClass(){super();}
      @Override public String toString(){ return "Blocked toString"; }
  }
```

Is there any way to force this "casting" from the returned MyClass instance to my newly particular subtype??

NOTE: Please, not suggest the approach of making a constructor, passing the original object and having to copy and implement the 150 methods to call the wrapped object

Comment: You didn't mention, even though you wrote `MyClass`. Is returned instance a class or an interface?

Comment: @Less Well since the `MyWrapperClass` extends `MyClass` then it has to be a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If MyClass is an interface look at [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and [java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html).

You can implement a *dynamic* proxy that always does the same. It is, always pass control to your original implementation... except when method X is invoked.

Something like:

```
class MyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
  Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
    if (method is the one you want to change) {
       do whatever
    else
       return method.invoke(originalObject, args);
  }
}
```

**Note:** you must create this proxy implementation anyway:

```
MyClass original = ServiceUtil.getThing();
MyClass proxy = (MyClass) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                                          MyClass.class.getClassLoader(), // classloader to use
                                          new Class[] { MyClass.class }, // interfaces to implement
                                          new MyHandler()); // who does the dirty work when methods are invoked
```

Comment: And... if you like this I should put the proxy creation stuff inside a `MyClass decorate(MyClass)` method, to put all the dirty stuff together. If you tomorrow want to change the way decoration works you only change that method. Your *normal* code doesn't get polluted.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking

Answer (score 5):

I hope I get you right: you have a

```
MyClass instance = ServiceUtil.getThing();
```

but want something like

```
MyWrapperClass instance = (MyWrapperClass) ServiceUtil.getThing();
```

(which obviously doesn't work, even though `MyWrapperClass` extends `MyClass`).

The solution is to create a new instance of `MyWrapperClass` based on the `MyClass` and, sorry to say that, using the constructor is a good approach (`public MyWrapperClass(MyClass myClass)`).

Comment: Of course it is, but then I would need to rewrite a call to super for the other 150 methods (as proxy methods to underlying object), which is not a nice pattern.

Comment: A class with 150 methods isn't a nice pattern anyway. So it won't get much worse ;)

Comment: An API returning classes not interfaces (and they're not simple value-objects) is not a nice pattern either. But the API is what it is....

Comment: Thank you. Everything is a fictional example for understanding best pattern in those situations. I understand when there is only 2 or 3 methods to override that wrapper is nice, but that is why i am asking what to do if there is a loooot of methods and u dont want to miss any

Answer (score 1):

> Please, not suggest the approach of making a constructor, passing the original object 
>   and having to copy and implement the 150 methods to call the wrapped object

You mean to say that "decoration" is not an option you would like to look at right?

But decoration will be a problem to you if MyClass is an interface type where you have to define those 150 odd methods, delegating the 149 method calls onto the decorated and overriding that one method.

If MyClass is a class type, then you don't need to write those 149 methods, right? or Did I get you completely wrong?

Comment: His class `MyWrapperClass` *extends* `MyClass`, so `MyClass` can't be an interface.

Comment: The problem is that he's being passed an instance, rather than instatiating one himself

Comment: exactly. If not, I could do an anonymous class instantiation overriding method, for example